# Adding new fields to DE stuck on 'saving fields'

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a Salesforce DE that is being used as source DE for many filtered DEs. Now if i want to add new fields to the source DE, the interface will just stuck on this 'Saving Fields' screen.
[image]

i've tried adding the new field via email studio, couldn't do it from contact builder as it is a salesforce data extension, it doesn't exist in contact builder.

is there any condition that i should do before adding new fields ? i've even cleared the data from the DE but it still stuck.

thanks guys.

Comment: right, found the solution. i moved the DE into a regular DE Folder so it can be detected in Contact Builder, and add the new field from CB, one-by-one..